# Include a CSV containing math symbols within a knitr xtable

Tags: csv, latex, knitr, xtable

Im trying to generate an xtable of a .csv file within a knitr document. The csv file contains cells which have several math symbols such as '±'.I do not know how to tell xtable to include that math symbol within the knitr document.

Thus far i have been trying the following

```
    table<-read.csv("table.csv",check.names = FALSE)
    q<-xtable(table,
          caption = "This is my table",include.rownames=FALSE,label="tab:table")
    print(q,include.rownames=FALSE)
```

This doesn't work and gives me the following error "missing $ inserted"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you read in a CSV is irrelevant.  It is a data.frame after `read.csv()`.

The result of `xtable()` can be post-processed as illustrated on the help page.  However, if these math symbols appear only in a column or two, it is easier to pre-process your `table`, wrapping the cell entries in `$ ... $`.

e.g.,

```
table[,1] <- paste0("$", table[,1], "$")
```